# Elasticsearch aggregation with hierarchical category, subcategory; limit the levels

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have products with categories field. Using the aggregation I can get the full categories with all subcategories. I want to limit the levels in the facet.

e.g. I have the facets like:

```
auto, tools & travel    (115)
auto, tools & travel > luggage tags (90)
auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters  (40)
auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > something else    (50)
auto, tools & travel > car organizers   (25)
```

Using aggregation like

```
"aggs": {
    "cat_groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.keyword",
        "size": 10,
       "include": "auto, tools & travel > .*"
      }
    }
}
```

I am getting buckets like

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags",
          "doc_count": 90
        },
        {
          "key": "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters",
          "doc_count": 40
        },
        {
          "key": "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > something else",
          "doc_count": 50
        },
        {
          "key": "auto, tools & travel > car organizers",
          "doc_count": 25
        }
]
```

But I want to limit the level. e.g. I want to get only the results for `auto, tools & travel > luggage tags`. How can I limit the levels?
By the way, `"exclude": ".* > .* > .*"`  does not work for me.

**I need to get buckets for different levels according to search. Sometimes first level, and sometimes second or third. When I want first level, I don't want the second levels to appear on buckets; and so on for other levels.**

Elasticsearch version 6.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've been able to figure the below technique.

I have implemented a `custom analyzer` using [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) and I have created multi-field called `categories` so that you can use `categories.facets` for aggregations/facets and do normal text search using `categories`.

The custom analyzer would only apply for `categories.facets`

Do note the property `"fielddata": "true"` for my field `categories.facet`

### Mapping

```
PUT myindex
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": ">"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "categories": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "facet": { 
              "type":  "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "fielddata": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST myindex/mydocs/1
{
    "categories" : "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters"
}

POST myindex/mydocs/2
{
    "categories" : "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters"
}

POST myindex/mydocs/3
{
    "categories" : "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters"
}

POST myindex/mydocs/4
{
    "categories" : "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > something else"
}
```

### Query

You can try the below query which you are looking for. Again I've implemented [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) because you need only specific words along with [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "facets": {
      "filter": { 
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "categories": "luggage"} }
            ]
         }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categories.facet"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Response

```
{
    "took": 43,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 11,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "facets": {
            "doc_count": 4,
            "categories": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "auto, tools & travel ",
                        "doc_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags ",
                        "doc_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > luggage spotters",
                        "doc_count": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "auto, tools & travel > luggage tags > something else",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Final Answer Post Discussion On Chat

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "facets": {
      "filter": { 
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "categories": "luggage"} }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categories.facet",
            "exclude": ".*>{1}.*>{1}.*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've added `exclude` with a `regular expression` in such a way that it would not consider any facets which is having more than one occurrence of `>`

Let me know this if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not do anything regarding limiting the category level.

Comment: @Mainuddin Could you check the answer now. I've updated it.

Comment: Can you please check the chatroom?

Comment: @Mainuddin I've finally been able to figure out. Please check the section `Final Answer Post Discussion On Chat` where I've added an `exclude` clause. Please accept the answer as it solves what you are looking for and if you have any doubts please do let me know.

Comment: @Mainuddin Posted an answer there! :)

Comment: Hi, just wonder if there is a solution without setting `fielddata` to `true`... To me it is not possible as `path_tokenizer` only applies to `text` field. Am I correct?

Comment: @MiDaa Yes that is correct. It only applies to `text` field as `keyword` doesn't make use of `analyzer`. Unless you have huge size of data for that field, you do not have to worry about the performance part. Its been said to use `keyword` instead of using `text` with `fielddata: true` when it comes to `sorting` and `aggregation` queries, but it doesn't apply to this case, in other ways this is the only option we have. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Kamal Thanks for the detailed explanations. I have implemented this way and it works well !

Comment: @Kamal Just did :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an integer field named level signifying your category's level in the hierarchy. Just count the number of occurrence of your delimiter '>' and save it as the value. Then add a rangeQuery to your boolQuery.

Add this to your schema:

```
"level": {
    "type": "integer",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "true"
}
```

In your code you have something like this which counts the number of delimiter suggesting the level of hierarchy (no delimiter means main category):

```
public Builder(final String path) {
    this.path = path;
    this.level = StringUtils.countMatches(path, DELIMITER);
}
```

and then your query search could have something like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "category": {
                            "value": "auto, tools & travel",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "level": {
                            "from": 2,
                            "to": 4,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can help him better by providing some demo code :)